# retrieve multiple data for jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I hava datatable which returns 25 records at clientside (out of 100 records). Along with those 25 rows, i want one array or any data structure which contains first column of all 100 records

My code:

```
var oTable = $('#tblClipart').dataTable({
        'bStateSave': true,        
        'bProcessing': true,
        'bServerSide': true,
        'aaSorting': [[6, 'desc']],
        'bFilter': false,
        'iDisplayLength': 25,
        'sPaginationType': "bootstrap",
        'sDom': 'Rlfrtlip',
        'aoColumns': [
            // Some Code
            ],
    'sAjaxSource': '/Handlers/Manage.ashx' // Handler page for providing data
});
```

Handler Code

```
List<ClipartEntity> clipArtEntityList = null;
clipArtEntityList = //Get Data From Server - All 100 Records

var result = new
{
    iTotalRecords = totalRecords,
    iTotalDisplayRecords = totalRecords, //Display only first 25     
    /* ClipartIds = clipArtEntityList.Select(m => m.ClipartID ), Can add this line to retrieve just one column in array list */
    aaData = clipArtEntityList
        .Select(p => new[] { 
            Convert.ToString("C"+p.ClipartID), 
            p.ClipartName + Convert.ToString(p.Sequence), 
            Convert.ToString(p.CategoryName),           
            Convert.ToString(p.ClipartID),
            p.ClipartNameForSort
        })
        .Skip(iDisplayStart)
        .Take(iDisplayLength)
};

var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = serializer.Serialize(result);
context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
context.Response.Write(json);
```

I can add `ClipartIds = clipArtEntityList.Select(m => m.ClipartID ),` to `var result` variable to get all 100 records first column data in `array` format

**But problem is how to retrieve it in client side ?**

P.S. I dont want to make another ajax call just to retrieve one column data as because my previous ajax call contains that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the [fnServerData](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnServerData) callback..  You've already created a custom `ClipartIds` return parameter, so to use it client-side, just add the callback to your datatables initialisation:

```
var oTable = $('#tblClipart').dataTable({
    'fnServerData': function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
            $.getJSON(sSource, aoData, function (json) {
                // do something with the column of Ids
                var clipartIds = json.ClipartIds;
                fnCallback(json);
            });
        },
    'bStateSave': true,
    ...
```